# Text to Image, keep getting error "no images defined"

Tags: image, text, imagemagick

for testing purposes, i am using imagemagick (the most actual portable windows version) to get a text to an image. so i type the following:

```
convert -font Arial -pointsize 22 -fill black -draw "text 0,0 'TESTTEXT'" test.jpg
```

but i keep getting this error:

```
convert.exe: no images defined `test.jpg' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3127.
```

Can someone tell me why?

Greetings

Answer (score 3):

Try adding a *canvas* and specifying a size with `-size 200x100 xc:#ff0000`

```
convert -size 200x100 xc:#ff0000 \
    -font Arial -pointsize 22 \
    -fill black -gravity center \
    -draw "text 0,0 'TESTTEXT'" test.jpg
```

PS I also added `-gravity center` to center the text inside output image

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this problem because I had both 32-bit and 64-bit versions of ImageMagick installed on my system. Removing the latter solved it.